# How to implement RPC client on Windows

Tags: c, linux, rpc, xml-rpc

It is convenient for programmers to implement rpc client and server on Linux by using command rpcgen to generate the client stub and the server stub automaticly.
Now I want to implement a rpc client on Windows to call procedures from the server on Linux. In Linux, we can use command like *gcc -Wall -o test_client test_client.c test_clnt.c* to generate excutable program of the client, but how can I manage it on Windows?

Comment: Just as on Linux you need a c or c++ compiler to compile your sources. No difference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has its own version of [RPC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787851(v=ws.10).aspx). It works fine between Windows boxes only.

For interoperability you need to look at CORBA or WCF.